# How is the MSE calculated?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have trouble with the following problem:

> Consider the independent random variables $[X_1,\ldots,X_{19}]$ For each
> $i$ their probability mass function is given by $p(X_i=-1)$ = $p(X_i= 1) = p$ and $p(X_i= 0) = 1-2p$. We use $T = \frac{1}{38}\sum_{i=1}^{19}Xi^2 $ as an estimator for p. Compute its
> MSE if the real value of the parameter is p=0.1
>
> The answer is 1/475

I tried, but I got the wrong answer and I don't know why. I know the MSE is:

$Var(T) + (E[T]-p)^2$

$Var(T)$ = $Var(\frac{1}{38}\sum_{i=1}^{19}X_i^2)$ = $(\frac{19}{38})^2 Var(X_i^2)$ =$\frac{1}{4}Var(X_i^2)$

$Var(X_i^2) = E[X_i^4] - (E[X^2]^2) = (1*0.1 + 1*0.1) - (1*0.1 + 1*0.1)^2 = 0.2 - 0.04 = 0.16$

So $Var(T) = 0.25*0.16 - 0.04$

$E[T] $ = $E[\frac{1}{38}\sum_{i=1}^{19}X_i^2]$ = $\frac{1}{2}E[X_i^2]$

$E[Xi^2]$ = $(-1)^2 * 0.1 + 1 * 0.1 = 0.2$

So $E[T] = 0.1$

$MSE = 0.04 + (0.1-0.1)^2 \ne \frac{1}{475}$

Can I get feedback on my method?

Thanks,
Ter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in $\mathrm{Var}[T]$:

$$\mathrm{Var}\left(\frac{1}{38}\sum_{i=1}^{19}X_i^2\right)
 \stackrel? = \left(\frac{19}{38}\right)^2 Var\left(X_i^2\right).$$

This should be

$$\mathrm{Var}\left(\frac{1}{38}\sum_{i=1}^{19}X_i^2\right)
  = \left(\frac{1}{38}\right)^2 \mathrm{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{19}X_i^2\right)
  = \frac{19}{38^2} Var\left(X_i^2\right).$$

Your calculation gives the variance if all the $X_i$ are equal, not independent.
That is, it is
$\mathrm{Var}\left(\frac{1}{38} \times 19X_i^2\right).$

Answer (score 2):

First of all observe that

$$\mathbb{E}[T]=\frac{19}{38}\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\frac{19}{38}\cdot2p=p$$

Thus $T$ is unbiased for $p$

As T is unbiased $MSE(T)=\mathbb{V}[T]$

$$\mathbb{V}[T]=\frac{1}{38^2}19\mathbb{V}[X^2]=\frac{19}{38^2}[\mathbb{E}[X^4]-\mathbb{E}^2[X^2]]\frac{19}{38^2}2p(1-2p)=\frac{1}{38}p(1-2p)$$

that is $MSE(T)=\frac{1}{475}$ if $p=\frac{1}{10}$